# A simple example of a useful "RESTful" API using books as an example?

Tags: api, rest

Can some please confirm or correct my thinking:

```
GET test.com/book/books **- get a list of all books**
PUT test.com/book/new **- create a new book**
GET test.com/book/9780142423356/Charles-Dickens-Great-Expectations **- get a specific book**
```

Is it correct?

How does REST deal with concurrent users - two people writing to test.com/book/9780142423356/ for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More typical would be

```
GET /books - get a list of all books

POST /books - create a new book
  - or -
PUT /books/Charles-Dickens-Great-Expectations - create a new book

GET /books/9780142423356 - get a specific book
  - or -
GET /books/Charles-Dickens-Great-Expectations  - get a specific book
```

POST is used when the unique identifier for the book is not known. PUT is preferred when the creator of the resource knows the unique identifier.

As far as concurrency management, the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) has headers that will help, such as `etag`, `if-match`, and `if-none-match`.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I'm re-reading Twitter API and Roy Fielding paper and got confused again. To give a more concrete example, let's say a system/user1 does: PUT /books/9780142423356, how should I pass on the info that user1 is done editing?

Comment: Also how do I specify the API docs the user-friendly part of the URI? PUT /books/Charles-Dickens-Great-Expectations
 vs 
PUT /books/9780142423356 vs
 PUT /books/9780142423356/Charles-Dickens-Great-Expectations

Comment: @LechRzedzicki ? Each edit is an atomic action. The PUT (edit) either happens completely or not at all. A book only has a state of being edited if you manage that yourself, via a property or resource. There's no way to push that information down to the client .. they'll have to ask for it.

Comment: @LechRzedzicki I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

REST doesn't worry about concurrency because REST is programming model only.  It is up to you on how concurrency is managed.

Answer (score 1):

PUT is for updating, POST is used for creating new resources, but it is up to your implementation that while updating if resource doesn't exist you can create.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to concurrency you would have to manage that by yourself.

If you are using any layered approach for data CRUD operations, you have to code the DAL to handle concurrency.